# Read Logcat for my own App on Android Jelly Bean

Tags: android, logging, permissions, logcat, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I want to read out the Android Logcat information in my app. i tried with:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)

but this is not allowed since jelly bean and fails with the message:

logcat -d -v time
Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': Permission denied

But Google says that it should possible to read the log from the own app. But how? 
I think not over the exec call...

I am not interested obtaining logs from other apps or to root the device.

Comment: That's odd - I just typed `logcat -d -v time` into the application-userid shell provided by `connectbot` on a 4.3 device, and it worked fine.  Perhaps you could try that experiment for comparion.